# How can I join tables while limiting data for 2 latest rows in the third table?

Tags: mysql

How can I select all products with their category names and with only latest 2 prices for each product?

**Products**

```
id | product_name | category_id | created_at
```

**Prices**

```
id | price | product_id | created_at
```

**Categories**

```
id | category_name
```

This is my approach, it joins all data. If I put `LIMIT 2` on second `INNER JOIN` I get only two total rows. How do I get all products but with only  two latest prices for each product?

```
SELECT
    products.product_name,
    categories.category_name,
    prices.price
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        prices.price,
    prices.product_id
    FROM
        prices
    ORDER BY
        created_at DESC
) as prices 
ON prices.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.product_name, categories.category_name, prices.price
```

This data can be used to generate tables and to seed them

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('1', 'fruits');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('2', 'vegetables');
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES ('3', 'seeds');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `prices`;
CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('1', '2', '1', '2017-01-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('2', '3', '2', '2017-01-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('3', '4', '3', '2017-01-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('4', '2', '4', '2017-01-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('5', '5', '1', '2017-02-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('6', '6', '2', '2017-02-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('7', '3', '3', '2017-02-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('8', '2', '4', '2017-02-07 04:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('9', '3', '1', '2017-03-10 06:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('10', '6', '2', '2017-03-10 06:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('11', '7', '3', '2017-03-10 06:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('12', '3', '4', '2017-03-10 06:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('13', '5', '1', '2017-03-10 09:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('14', '2', '2', '2017-03-10 09:03:45');
INSERT INTO `prices` VALUES ('15', '6', '3', '2017-03-10 09:03:45');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `products`;
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `f_category` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('1', 'apples', '1', '2017-01-10');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('2', 'pears', '1', '2017-01-10');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('3', 'tomatoes', '2', '2017-01-10');
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('4', 'walnuts', '3', '2017-01-10');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT products.product_name, categories.category_name, p.id,p.price
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT p.id,p.price, p.product_id,
         if(p.product_id <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         @p:= p.product_id
FROM (select @rn:=0, @p:=0) rn,prices p
ORDER BY p.product_id, p.id DESC 
) AS p on p.product_id = products.id and (p.rn in (1,2))
order by products.id, p.id desc;
```

note:- tomato is a fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT
    products.product_name,
    categories.category_name,
    prices.price
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 2
        prices.price,
    prices.product_id
    FROM
        prices
    ORDER BY
        created_at DESC
) as prices
```

Comment: I use MySQL so I guess I can't use "SELECT TOP". But the result is same as @Muhammad wrote

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Using `LIMIT` on prices table.

```
SELECT products.product_name, categories.category_name, prices.price
FROM products
INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT prices.price, prices.product_id
FROM prices
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
LIMIT 2
) AS prices
```

Comment: This doesn't join correctly so if only apples have latest price 5555 then each product will have that price